# Using rownum in subquery

Tags: oracle, subquery, rownum

In an algorithm the users passes a query, for instance:

```
SELECT o_orderdate, o_orderpriority FROM h_orders WHERE rownum <= 5
```

The query returns the following:

```
1996-01-02  5-LOW
1996-12-01  1-URGENT
1993-10-14  5-LOW
1995-10-11  5-LOW
1994-07-30  5-LOW
```

The algorithm needs the count for the select attributes (`o_orderdate, o_orderpriority` in the above example) and therefore it rewrites the query to:

```
SELECT o_orderdate, count(o_orderdate) FROM 
  (SELECT o_orderdate, o_orderpriority FROM h_orders WHERE rownum <= 5) 
GROUP BY o_orderdate
```

This query returns the following:

```
1992-01-01  5
```

However the intended result is:

```
1996-12-01  1
1995-10-11  1
1994-07-30  1
1996-01-02  1
1993-10-14  1
```

Any idea how I could rewrite the parsing stage or how the user could pass a syntactically different query to receive the above results?

Comment: Actually, your query returns your intended result from the provided data - see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/93986/1 . Some mistake, surely?

Comment: There was an index on the table which caused this behaviour. Since the index was on both columns the database parser selected the tuples in order of the index. Now after I have dropped the index the example works as you have shown.

Answer (score 2):

The rows returned by the inner query are essentially non-deterministic, as they depend on the order in which the optimiser identifies rows as part of the required data set. A change in execution plan due to modified predicates might change the order in which the rows come back, and new rows added to the table can also change which rows are included.

Comment: That is true, but the query should just select n rows and it is not important which ones.

Comment: In that case, as Mark says in the question comment, your question is not consistent -- that is not the result that came from that query and that data. The only explanation is that the data projected from the inner query changed, so I suspect that the execution plan changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you always want `n` rows then either use `distinct(o_orderdate)` in the innerquery, which will render the `GROUP BY` useless.

Or you can add another outer `select` with `rownum` to get `n` of the grouped rows, like this:

```
select o_orderdate, counter from
(
    SELECT o_orderdate, count(o_orderdate) as counter FROM 
      (SELECT o_orderdate, o_orderpriority FROM h_orders) 

    GROUP BY o_orderdate
)
WHERE rownum <= 5
```

Although the results will most likely be useless as they will be undeterministic (as mentioned by David Aldridge).

Comment: The problem of this query is that it scans the whole h_orders relation. Currently the relation contains about 10^15 tuples. The table is just used for benchmarks and therefore different slices at the beginning of the execution are needed. The determinism does not change anything to the benchmarks results of the algorithm.

Comment: what about using the `distinct` keyword? you will always get `n` records, but they will all have 1 as a count. The behaviour of your original query is perfectly fine though if you don't need exactly `n` results.

Answer (score 0):

As your outer query makes no use of "o_orderpriority", why not just get rid of the subquery and simply query like this:

```
SELECT o_orderdate, count(o_orderdate) AS order_count
FROM h_orders
WHERE rownum <= 5
GROUP BY o_orderdate
```